# Java EE database Facade Connection Error

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, java-ee-7

I am trying to connect to a database using Facade. I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 JDK 1.7 and JAva EE 7.

There is a Enterprise Application, a client application couple of beans and a class library. I mostly used the insert code method in netbeans to create the connections. I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
   at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
   at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.launch(AppClientFacade.java:183)
   atorg.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientGroupFacade.main(AppClientGroupFacade.java:65)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
   at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy299.count(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

And

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [EntityType] was found for the key class [com.javaee.test.db.Questions] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.javaee.test.db.Questions</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entityEmbeddableManagedTypeNotFound(MetamodelImpl.java:173)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:193)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.CommonAbstractCriteriaImpl.internalFrom(CommonAbstractCriteriaImpl.java:114)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.AbstractQueryImpl.from(AbstractQueryImpl.java:246)
```

I am not sure where exactly the problem might be so i didn't post any of the code. If you have a hint I can put down the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error last night. I think we are taking the same class! To fix it expand the ejb project -> Configuration Files -> persistence.xml

Under General, there is a checked checkbox "Include All Entity Classes in **_** Module". I unchecked the box and then added each class manually. That took care of the exception. Hope this helps.